# case statement in where clause,should not check only for specific values

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need a CASE statement in where clause:

Lets say we have two tables X and Y

X has 3 columns, namely `EmpId,Name,JoinDate,DeptID`

Y has 4 columns, namely `EmpId,JoinDate,DeptID,DeptRefCd`

I've to get the results so that except for X.deptId in (1,2,3) it should not check for X.JoinDate=ISNULL(Y.JoinDate,'').i.e., it have to ignore the JoinDate
condition deptId= 1 ,2 ,3

I've written as below,but its showing error:

```
 CASE 
    WHEN X.deptId NOT IN (1,2,3)  THEN X.JoinDate=ISNULL(Y.JoinDate,'')
 END
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You don't need `CASE`. You need basic boolean logic - `AND`s, `OR`s and `NOT`s.

Comment: can you give me query for that ....if possible with a small example

Comment: So, if `X.JoinDate=ISNULL(Y.JoinDate,'')` is true, you'd want to include that row anyway, correct? And if `X.deptid in (1,2,3)` was true, you'd want to include that row? So, you have two conditions, and if *either* of them is true, you'd want to include that row. If it happens that both are true, you don't need to do anything special, and you'd still want to include those rows. So, it sounds like you have two conditions that you could just insert an `OR` between.

Comment: if X.deptid in (1,2,3) i dont want to check for X.JoinDate=ISNULL(Y.JoinDate,'').. if X.deptid in (7,8,9) etcc... it should consider X.JoinDate=ISNULL(Y.JoinDate,'')

Comment: But there's no **harm** in also checking it in that case, is there? Is it really of vital importance that it *not* be checked?

Comment: Yeah! if satisfies  X.deptid in (1,2,3).. it should not check for X.JoinDate=ISNULL(Y.JoinDate,'')

Comment: If you see a `WHERE` clause that specifies `i=1 or j=2` do you think that's normal or do you go out of your way to write complex logic that avoids the `j=2` check if `i` is `1`? Because that's what you're effectively doing here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you want.  I am assuming that in addition to the join you don't know how to create, the tables need to join on `EmpID`.

```
SELECT [whatever columns you want]
FROM   X
   JOIN Y
       ON X.EmpID = Y.EmpID 
      AND (X.deptId IN (1,2,3) 
       OR (X.deptId NOT IN (1,2,3) AND X.JoinDate=ISNULL(Y.JoinDate,'')))
```

Also, joins that involve `ISNULL` tend to be very slow because indexes can't be used on the underlying columns.  But that may not be an issue, depending on how big your tables are.